# How to assign dynamic column names in data.table under `:=`?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the below code :

```
library(data.table)
carsDT <- data.table(cars)
carsDT[speed < 15, `:=`(paste0("col", 1)=1 paste0("col", 2)=2)]
```

This code gives the error :

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "carsDT[speed < 15, `:=`(paste0("col", 1)="
```

Is there any way, that inside `:=`, I can use dynamic column names? I know that I can do above like this :

```
carsDT[speed < 15, (paste0("col", 1)) := 1]
carsDT[speed < 15, (paste0("col", 2)) := 2]
```

This solution will involve many lines of code(number of columns to be assigned is in 100s). It will be convenient if I can do all the assignments under single `:=`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can place the values in a `list` or use `.(...)` and then assign (`:=`) it to new columns

```
carsDT[speed < 15, paste0("col", 1:2) := list(1, 2)]
```